# Is there a way to split one long insert statement into 2 in SQL backup file?

Tags: mysql, sql, backup, database-backups

Currently I have a backup up SQL file of a MySQL database where the database is already dead. I want to rebuild the MySQL database again but when I import the SQL file, it says `Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`, which I found the error is caused by the fact that the insert statement is too long.

I don't have the permission to increase the `max_allowed_packet` of the database. The whole file is around 5 GB and it is too painful to split the insert statements by hand. Is there any tool I can automatically split long statement into 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can open that large file using [Large Text File Reader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/largetextfile/) , split the file then manually adjust the last part of first file and first part of the 2nd file.